# VueJS How to wait for axios data before continuing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code, that should parse data into variable and then send a post request.

The problem is, I need one property from API and I don't know how can I wait before it's returned.

```
addFieldData(data, generatorData) {
      this.populateModel(data);

      console.log(this.model);

      this.$axios.post('data/webform/fields', this.model)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);

          this.$notify({
            group: "app",
            title: this.$t("general.success"),
            text: this.$t("general.action_has_been_processed"),
            type: "info"
          });
        }).catch(error => {
            this.$notify({
                group: "app",
                title: this.$t("general.error"),
                text: this.$t("general.error_occured"),
                type: "error"
            });
          console.log(error);
      });
    },
    populateModel(data) {
      this.model.label = data.label ?? {};
      this.model.hint = data.placeholder ?? {};
      this.model.attributes = data.attributes ?? {};
      this.model.maxlength = data.maxlength ?? 0;
      this.model.position = this.getFieldPosition();
      this.model.required = data.required ?? true;
      this.model.visible = data.visible ?? true;
      this.model.disabled = data.disabled ?? false;
      this.model.style_classes = data.style_classes ?? "";
      this.model.model = data.model ?? "";
      this.model.default = data.default ?? "";
      this.model.input_type = data.input_type ?? "";
      this.model.hint = data.hint ?? "";
      this.model.help = data.help ?? "";
      this.model.type = data.type;
    },
    async getFieldPosition() {
      const res = await this.$axios.get('/data/webform/' + this.idWebform + '/itemsCount');
      this.model.position = res.data.data.count + 1;
      return res.data.data.count;
    },
```

In the addFieldData I call populateModel which should get position from API, but the post request is called before the getFieldPosition returns the data.

I'd like to try wait for the getFieldPosition first and then send the post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should have everything with `async/await` without any `.then`.
Don't mix both of them. Use the first one.

Then, in your `async populateModel` method, you should have a

```js
this.model.position = await this.getFieldPosition()
```

since `getFieldPosition` is async.